# mapping arbitrary frequency to midi note using audiokit microtonality

Tags: frequency, midi, audiokit

I am trying to map midi notes (defined in one octave) to change the output of an example application (dunneaudiokit synth). Is there a way to change the mapping without getting into the guts of the application which plays midi notes? I saw one question about this but looking for an example. Given a frequency array of 12 notes how to remap all midi outputs to these frequencies and their octaves? Thanks

I've tried the following:

```
import Microtonality

class DunneSynthConductor: ObservableObject, HasAudioEngine {
   let engine = AudioEngine()
   var instrument = Synth()
    
// let midiTuning = TuningTableBase()
   TuningTableBase.setFrequency(690, at: 69)
```

which caused syntax errors.

Comment: Unclear what you’re trying to achieve. DunneAudioKit is not an external app but a framework. Please show more code you have tried.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to change to tuning of the keyboard and for instance assign designated frequencies to notes. I gather that's what Microtonality is about but unsure how to use it. Thx

Comment: Yes, that's what Microtonality is used for. Are you using an external MIDI-Keyboard?

Comment: I have recompiled the AK cookbook examples (dunnesynth) to play on the iPad.